# How to redirect to an anchor in JSF?

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, accessibility, anchor

Let's say I have this action in a JSF Managed Bean:

```
public String doSomething() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("msg", "Something was done successfully");
    return "view?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

My `view` has an anchor element with the id `msg`. I want the url to have this anchor (for accessibility matters), like:

```
view.jsf#msg
```

Or whatever is my FacesServlet filter pattern.

`return "view#msg?faces-redirect=true";` obviously will not work because JSF (mojarra at least) will try to evaluate `view#msg` as a view.

So my question is how to make JSF redirect to a URL with `#msg` in the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *because JSF (mojarra at least) will try to evaluate `view#msg` as a view*

Oh, that's nasty. It's definitely worth an enhancement request at the JSF/Mojarra boys.

Your best bet is to send the redirect manually with help of [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void doSomething() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.getFlash().put("msg", "Something was done successfully");
    ec.redirect("view.xhtml#msg");
}
```

*(assuming that `FacesServlet` is mapped on `*.xhtml`)*

Alternatively, you could conditionally render a piece of JS which does that instead.

```xml
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty flash.msg}">
    <script>window.location.hash = 'msg';</script>
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: Good thought that piece of JS. Also, `ExternalContext#redirect()` works greatly. Once again, a nice answer :)

Comment: I want to add, that if you want to jump to an anchor on the same page, redirect reloads, so the JS is the better option. Don't forget to put the code after the element you want to jump to.

Answer (score 0):

You try to build an illegal URL - the fragment (`#`) is always the last part of an URL.

`return "view?faces-redirect=true#msg"` would be the correct URL.

Unfortunately that fragment is stripped by the default `NavigationHandler`, at least in JSF 2.2.

While the two options of [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601642#6601776) are working as well, I have a third option to offer. Wrap the `NavigationHandler` and `ViewHandler` with a small patch:

```
public class MyViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    public static final String REDIRECT_FRAGMENT_ATTRIBUTE = MyViewHandler.class.getSimpleName() + ".redirect.fragment";

    // ... Constructor and getter snipped ...

    public String getRedirectURL(final FacesContext context, final String viewId, final Map<String, List<String>> parameters, final boolean includeViewParams) {
        final String redirectURL = super.getRedirectURL(context, viewId, removeNulls(parameters), includeViewParams);
        final Object fragment = context.getAttributes().get(REDIRECT_FRAGMENT_ATTRIBUTE);
        return fragment == null ? redirectURL : redirectURL + fragment;
    }

}

public class MyNavigationHandler extends ConfigurableNavigationHandlerWrapper {

    // ... Constructor and getter snipped ...

    public void handleNavigation(final FacesContext context, final String fromAction, final String outcome) {
        super.handleNavigation(context, fromAction, 
            storeFragment(context, outcome));
    }

    public void handleNavigation(final FacesContext context, final String fromAction, final String outcome, final String toFlowDocumentId) {
        super.handleNavigation(context, fromAction, 
            storeFragment(context, outcome), toFlowDocumentId);
    }

    private static String storeFragment(final FacesContext context, final String outcome) {
        if (outcome != null) {
            final int hash = outcome.lastIndexOf('#');
            if (hash >= 0 && hash + 1 < outcome.length() && outcome.charAt(hash + 1) != '{') {
                context.getAttributes().put(MyViewHandler.REDIRECT_FRAGMENT_ATTRIBUTE, outcome.substring(hash));
                return outcome.substring(0, hash);
            }
        }
        return outcome;
    }
}
```

(I had to create the wrapper for the ViewHandler anyway, because of a fix for JAVASERVERFACES-3154)